# Is it idiomatic to use "the garbage" to refer to "trash can"?

Tags: word-usage

It sounds like the video is [saying](https://youtu.be/OyIytwRIKTM?t=67) (link with a time stamp corresponds the following)

> dump it to the garbage

Is it idiomatic to use "the garbage" to refer to "trash can"?

it might also be that she mispronounced or I misheard.

Answer (score 1):

This [metonymic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy) use of the word "garbage" is grammatical and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't hear *to*. *Dump it in the garbage* is idiomatic, but I wouldn't characterize it as using *the garbage* to mean *trash can*, exactly. A *trash can* is a physical object, but *the garbage* is a more abstract and general concept. Putting something is a dumpster, down a garbage chute, in a garbage bag, etc. can be considered putting it in the garbage. Also, some people make a distinction of *trash* being dry waste such as papers versus *garbage* including wet waste.